# Calendar Events in Multiple languages

Tags: internationalization, calendar, liferay, liferay-6, multilingual

I need to use Liferay 6.1 calendar but it seems like it does not support multilanguage (i.e. language translations) for events.

When I insert a new event it doesn't show me the "Add translation" feature.

I don't know if this exists as an update of the plugin, I'm already using an hook over it but the main problem is to have more than one title, i.e. one for each language.

Anyone know how I can solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you cann't make this with a hook, but with Ext. Because this requirement need to change the EditEventAction.java of Liferay Core. Thus change you can make only with a Ext. Futermore you must change the edit_event.jsp and the evet views jsps. Here a screenshot how this can [image]see if you make it:

Comment: Even if you make it with a `EXT` the problem of storing the languages would still be there. You would also have to change a lot of `add`, `update` and `display` logic since you need to store additional information then what liferay provides. If you still need to go ahead then I suppose it would help checking out the code for `web-content` portlet as to how the title's in different languages are shown and stored. In my opinion it would be a considerable effort.

Comment: yes, here is something to do :) But, after that change request is done, you know how Liferay core works.